# How to print 2-ngrams in LimeTextExplainer

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, lime

I try to explain the importance of a sentence using the following pipeline with `LimeTextExplainer` from LIME package.

```py
Pipeline(steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf', LogisticRegression())])
```

When I try to explain a sentence using the code below, the "importance" of the single words is shown, while I want pairs

```py
explainer.explain_instance(text, cls.predict_proba, num_features=7)
exp.show_in_notebook(text=False)
```

[image]
Is it possible to display the importance of pairs of words?

Comment: The official repository of the `LimeTextExplainer` package has not yet added such functionality.  [see here](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/issues/7)